# Idiomatic Scala try option code block

Tags: beginner, scala, error-handling, null

Basically, this function returns a list of flights for an airline. But if the airline doesn't exist, I want to throw some custom runtime exception. If that airline does exist, I want to return a list of flights (which could potentially be empty).

Is this is the standard way of doing things in Scala, or is there a better way to write this code?

Coming from a Java background, I'm still trying to get to grips with the Scala way of doing things.

```
def getFlightsForAirline(id:Long):Try[Option[List[Flight]]] = {
     val maybeAirline:Option[Airline] = Airline.getById(id)

     maybeAirline match {
       case Some(airline) => {
          Success(Flight.getFlightsByAirline(airline))
       }
       case None => Failure(new RecordNotFoundException("Couldnt find airline"))
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The `maybeAirline` variable isn't necessary. Note that the type annotation in the declaration is optional, and can easily be inferred by the compiler. So I would change that to:

   ```
   def getFlightsForAirline(id: Long): Try[Option[List[Flight]]] =
     Airline.getById(id) match {
       case Some(airline) => Success(Flight.getFlightsByAirline(airline))
       case None => Failure(new RecordNotFoundException("Couldnt find airline"))
     }
   ```

   Notice that the Scala style guide [suggests putting a space after the colon](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#annotations) in a type annotation – `name: Type` instead of `name:Type`.
2. Every time you destructure an `Option` with `match/case`, they kill a puppy because you *should* have probably used `map`. Well, almost every time, because the `Failure` is an important part of this function's behaviour. But this still is somewhat of a code smell.
3. The return type `Try[Option[List[Flight]]]` strikes me as rather weird: What is the difference between `Success(Some(List()))` and `Success(None())`? I guess the latter might occur if `getFlightsByAirline` isn't passed a valid airline.

   `Try`, `Option` and `List` are essentially the same thing (either you get a result, or there isn't anything there: Failure, None or empty List). Therefore it does not make much sense to nest them, and it would be better to return a `Try[List[Flight]]`. This could be implemented along the lines of:

   ```
   def getFlightsForAirline(id: Long): Try[List[Flight]] =
     Airline.getById(id) flatMap { Flight.getFlightsByAirline(_) } match {
       case Some(flights) => Success(flights)
       case None => Failure(new RecordNotFoundException("Couldnt find airline"))
     }
   ```

   This way, the `Failure` is returned if either of the `getXByY` methods returns `None`.

   Interestingly, there is no builtin way to transform an `Option` to a `Try` (along the lines of `maybe toTry { MyException("Reason") }`) while there is a `try.toOption` method.
4. Your `RecordNotFoundException` will have a much more Scala-ish vibe if you use a [`case class`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) here. This way, you can omit the `new` to create a new instance, and just write: `Failure(RecordNotFoundException("..."))`

Comment: +1 for the `Option[List[...]]` type, seen it too many times where it doesn't make sense :). Also how about considering `Seq` instead of `List`?

Comment: Good. You might want to comment on the clarity of ```getFlightsForAirline``` and ```getFlightsByAirline``` as well. It is not obvious which you would like to use and how either of those would behave.

Comment: You can use a `map` here instead of a `flatMap`, cannot you?

Comment: @scand1sk No I cannot, that is the point of this exercise. Using Haskell's notation: `map :: (A → B) → M[A] → M[B]` and `fmap :: (A → M[B]) → M[A] → M[B]`. Translated into Scala, the former produces two nested `Option`s: `Option[Flight].map(Airline => Option[List[Flight]]): Option[Option[List[Flight]]]`, whereas `Option[Flight].flatMap(Airline => Option[List[Flight]]): Option[List[Flight]]`. In `map`, the thing inside the output container is returned. In `flatMap`, instances of the output container are returned, which are then concatenated to produce the final output.

Comment: You are right, I did not realized that `getFlightsForAirLine` returned an `Option`. I have seen cases where `Some(Nil)` have not the same semantics as `None`, but this one ought not to be such a case.

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic way of using `Option` is to use `map/flatMap` methods:

```
def getFlightsForAirline(id: Long): Try[List[Flight]] =
  Airline.getById(id) flatMap Flight.getFlightsByAirline map Success.apply getOrElse {
    Failure(new RecordNotFoundException("Couldnt find airline"))
  }
```

*Note*: this works, if you simplify returned type, e.g strip `Option`.

Otherwise, you need just change `flatMap` to `map`:

```
def getFlightsForAirline(id: Long): Try[Option[List[Flight]]] =
  Airline.getById(id) map Flight.getFlightsByAirline map Success.apply getOrElse {
    Failure(new RecordNotFoundException("Couldnt find airline"))
  }
```